# how can i get session value using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here is my code :

```
var activitytaskid = "<%= Session['currentTask']%>";
```

Am not able to get the session value with following key, please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: What is Session['currentTask']?

Comment: Where is that code? In a .js or .html file (that will not work as it is not processed by asp.net), or in an .aspx file (that should work, when you switch the quotes)?

Answer (score 3):

Please try modifying your code.

```
var activitytaskid = '<%= Session["currentTask"]%>';
```

And remember this will contain rendered value. The value of activitytaskid will be initialized at the time page is rendered.

**EDIT** 
Yes browser will show this string as session is server side so value will be rendered in javascript varaible.

So when you view source of html page, value will be displayed in plain text

Comment: browser is displaying this whole as a string.

Comment: Sorry this is not working for me, so i just take the value of session in a hidden field and fetch that hidden value in js.

Answer (score 0):

Is this java? If so that should read "session" with a lowercase 's'. If the case is correct, make sure you have set the currentTask session variable somewhere.

Comment: The question is tagged "C#" and "asp.net", so it's not java.